# Copy Paste Table using Variable

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2007

I want to store a table in variable `cTable` and paste this whenever I need it with all formatting.

```
Sub copytable()
Dim cTable As TABLE

    Selection.Tables(1).Select

    cTable = Selection.Tables ' how do i assign table into variable

    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=2

    Selection.Paste cTable ' how it going to be paste exacty the copied table

End Sub
```

Example is in table image :

[image]

@ken This is simple code of copy / paste table without `variable`

```
Selection.Tables(1).Select
Selection.COPY
Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=2
Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdPasteDefault)
```

Comment: Record a macro where you select the table, copy it, move to the new location, and paste it. Then look at the macro code to see how you need to do it yourself.

Comment: This is for Word, why have you included the Excel tag? I'll remove it when I get a chance.

Comment: @AndyG sorry bro I though `excel` folks may contribute to this issue

Comment: Excel folks would assume it is an Excel question.. Anyway, I've removed it.

Comment: @KenWhite it works fine when paste table only once. but I need to copy/ paste some other thing in-between doing some other stuff. so storing `table` in `variable` should work but I don't know how to store table with formatting.

Comment: The macro code will show you how to store the table to a variable, and you can do whatever you want to the code after it's recorded - add to it, remove things from it, have it repeat things, or whatever. Recording the macro gives you the starting code that does exactly what you've asked for here: Select a table, assign it to a variable, and then paste it somewhere else.

Comment: @KenWhite while doing `cTable = Selection.text` it store as `text` my simple question is how do i store table into `cTable` with all formatting. take a look I have edited OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to store a table *in* a variable. It is possible to use a variable to *reference* a table, so that you can always refer back to it.

This code sample demonstrates how it doesn't matter whether new tables are inserted before or after the table being referenced. If it was the first table in the document and it's copied to the beginning of the document, it can still be copied to the end of the document (or anywhere else).

```
Sub ReuseTableReference()
    Dim doc As word.Document
    Dim tbl As word.Table
    Dim rngTableTarget As word.Range

    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    Set tbl = doc.Tables(1)
    Set rngTableTarget = doc.content

    'Copy the table to the beginning of the document
    rngTableTarget.Collapse wdCollapseStart
    rngTableTarget.FormattedText = tbl.Range.FormattedText

    'Copy the table to the end of the document
    rngTableTarget.Start = doc.content.End
    rngTableTarget.FormattedText = tbl.Range.FormattedText

    'Copy the table to the current selection
    Selection.FormattedText = tbl.Range.FormattedText
End Sub
```

Hard-coding in index value is often not desirable, of course. In that case, the table can be bookmarked so that you can pick it up from the bookmark, instead:

```
    Set tbl = doc.Bookmarks("tbl").Range.Tables(1)
```

(Here, the index value 1 refers to the number of tables within the bookmarked Range.)